# I am trying to plot a graph using xyplot function, but the is no output

Tags: metadata

everyone I am trying to plot a graph using xyplot function.The code runs
 without any output. Could anyone help or advice on how to overcome this challenge.

```
print(xyplot(ASEggerTest ~ rho, data = res, groups = tau))
print(xyplot(ASEggerTest ~ rho, data = res, groups = Odds))
print(xyplot(ASEggerTest ~ rho, data = res, groups = p))
print(xyplot(ASEggerModel, data = res, groups = rho))
print(xyplot(SchwarzerTest~ rho, data = res, groups = tau))
print(xyplot(SchwarzerTest ~ rho, data = res, groups = Odds))
print(xyplot(SchwarzerTest ~ rho, data = Fixed, groups = p))
print(xyplot(SchwarzerModel, data = res, groups = rho))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share more details like some sample data?

Comment: @Nico Haase, thank you for your response.  I simulated the data.

Comment: Can you share the process of simulating the data? Without input data, it's nearly impossible to reproduce your problem